# No Errors and Success Messages are showing in JQuery Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Hello I was learning Jquery and created a form and wrote some functions with the help of tutorials but not getting the results on the form. Quite confused about the actual error.

```
           function isEmail(email) {
               var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
               return regex.test(email);
           }    
            $("#buttonSubmit").click(function() {
                var errorMessage = "";
                var fieldsMissing = "";

            if ($("#email").val()  == "") {
                fieldsMissing += "<br>Email Missing"
            }
            if ($("#mobile").val()  == "") {
                fieldsMissing += "<br>Mobile Number Missing"
            }
            if ($("#password").val()  == "") {
                fieldsMissing += "<br>Enter Your Passowrd"
            }
            if ($("#passwordConfirm").val()  == "") {
                fieldsMissing += "<br>Confirm password"
            }
            if  (isEmail($("#email").val())==false) {
                errorMessage += "<p>Enter Your valid email</p>"
            } 
            if  (isNumeric($("#mobile").val())==false) {
                errorMessage += "<p>Enter Your valid mobile number</p>"
            } 
            if  ($("#password").val()!=$("#passwordConfirm").val()) {
                errorMessage += "<p>Your Password Don't Match</p>"
            }
            if (errorMessage != "") {
                $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
            } else {
                $("successMessage").show();
                $("errorMessage").hide();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you please provide us the console information while executing this code?

Comment: There is no error in console. That is why i am a bit confused about why the messages are not showing properly.

Comment: Because your code is not fired, you should take your handlers inside document ready
$(document).ready(function() {......yourcode.........});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot to all actually now i got the actual error after some hours.The errors are missing string on an error message and a whole syntax of updating field missing message.

```
if ($.isNumeric($("#mobile").val()) == false) {
        errorMessage += "<p>Enter Your valid mobile number</p>"
      }
and 

                   if (fieldsMissing != "") {
                        errorMessage += "<p>The Following Field(s) are Missing!</p>" + fieldsMissing;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of your code, you can update according to your needs..

```js
function isEmail(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return regex.test(email);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonSubmit").click(function() {
    var errorMessage = "";
    var fieldsMissing = "";

    if ($("#email").val() == "") {
      errorMessage += "<br>Email Missing"
    }
    if ($("#mobile").val() == "") {
      errorMessage += "<br>Mobile Number Missing"
    }
    if ($("#password").val() == "") {
      errorMessage += "<br>Enter Your Passowrd"
    }
    if ($("#passwordConfirm").val() == "") {
      errorMessage += "<br>Confirm password"
    }
    if (isEmail($("#email").val()) == false) {
      errorMessage += "<p>Enter Your valid email</p>"
    }
    if ($.isNumeric($("#mobile").val()) == false) {
      errorMessage += "<p>Enter Your valid mobile number</p>"
    }
    if ($("#password").val() != $("#passwordConfirm").val()) {
      errorMessage += "<p>Your Password Don't Match</p>"
    }
    if (errorMessage != "") {
      $("#errorMessage").html(errorMessage);
      $("errorMessage").show();
    } else {
      $("successMessage").show();
      $("errorMessage").hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" type="text" placeholder="email">
<br><br>
<input id="mobile" type="text" placeholder="mobile">
<br><br>
<input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password">
<br><br>
<input id="passwordConfirm" type="password" placeholder="passwordConfirm">
<br><br>


<div id="successMessage"></div>
<div id="errorMessage"></div>

<button id="buttonSubmit" type="submit">Submit Button</button>
```